# XLOOKUP function if columns misplaced

Tags: excel, google-sheets, xlookup, index-match

I have two sheets, Both Sheet1 & Sheet2 consists of 6 columns which are:

- Shop Name
- Shop status
- Business Type
- City
- Operating hours
- Delivery model

The below INDEX MATCH Function finds shop name in Sheet2 and returns exact values of shop status against each Shop name:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$H,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A,0),MATCH(B$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$H$1,0))
```

which also can locate Shop status values if it's misplaced in Sheet2, I need that Xlookup  function to the same as the above INDEX MATCH function `=XLOOKUP($A2:A,Sheet2!$A$2:$A,Sheet2!$B$2:$B)`.

Please find the attached [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gHi3QMayWGbfxgRKeJzdm4F7JG_U7jIMe1_ltaLHO3A/edit?usp=sharing) where it shows an example of the above:
In Sheet1 Cell B2, INDEX MATCH function still returns exact match even though I changed data in Sheet2 to be in column D, however XLOOKUP in B3 returns nothing as still search for date in column B in Sheet2.

Comment: Lets start with this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am with @DavidLeal here, please provide a sample sheet based on the reference link provided in the comment.

Comment: Hello @Babanana, I attached an example with published sheet, you can find link in the post after editing.

Comment: @BarnetLatoya  Are you looking for something like this? `=XLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:A,Sheet2!$D$2:D)` I have test it and should show you the same result as you current formula. Please let me know so I can post this as an answer and let the community find this post to help them on their projects as well. If it is not please let me know so I can have a better understanding of your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a simpler INDEX-MATCH inside XLOOKUP to find the correct column:

```
=XLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A,INDEX (Sheet2!$B$2:$H,,MATCH(B$1,Sheet2!$B$1:$H$1,0)))
```

PS: it's not clear why you need to transform it into a XLOOKUP

Comment: Thanks Martin, the reason to change to XLOOKUP is that I couldn't use INDEX-MATCH with ARRAYFORMULA function, if you do have a resolution for that, please advise.